# how to get days of difference between two dates in php

Tags: php, laravel, date

Hello I want to get days of between two different dates.

```
$expire_date = ("2019-07-22")
$current_date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
$interval = $expire_date->diffIndays($current_date)->days;
dd($interval);
```

display this error:

> Call to a member function diffIndays() on string

Comment: `$expire_date` isn't a Carbon instance. Are you getting this value from the database?

Comment: So, `$expire_date` is really a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to make your `$expire_date` into a `Carbon` instance:

```
$expire_date = Carbon::parse("2019-07-22");
```

Then `diffInDays()` already returns the days so you just need to remove `->days`. Lastly, don't convert the current date into  a string:

```
$interval = $expire_date->diffIndays(now());
```